# SonicWall configuration

Tags: router, sonicwall, modem

I currently have a SonicWall and I'm attempting to connect it to my router or modem's LAN interface. This is for testing and will not be the network design in production. When I plug it in with the WAN interface of the SonicWall to the LAN interface of the router or modem it doesn't automatically pick up and I don't know where to go from here. The SonicWall does not have the DHCP server enabled so the router can pick it up. It does detect a WAN link.

Can provide details as asked, I'm just new to SonicWALL so I won't even know what to provide.

Comment: `When I plug it in with the WAN interface of the SonicWall to the LAN interface of the router or modem it doesn't automatically pick up and I don't know where to go from here` - Doesn't pick up what?

Comment: An IP, the WAN connection, etc.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear, it's just I'm inexperienced with SonicWall AND this isn't a very conventional firewall setup (normally I'd just stick it in front of everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume this is your setup:

```
ROUTER >----> SNWL X1 (WAN) >----> SNWL X0 (LAN) >----> YOUR PC
```

By default, SNWL LAN interface (X0) has IP 192.168.168.168. You can set your PC with 192.168.168.10/24, gateway 192.168.168.168. Now, pointing your browser at https://192.168.168.168 you will see SonicWall webUI auth page. You can login with user: "admin" and pass: "password".

To the left, you will see a tree-like menu. Open "Network" and, on the left, edit the X1 (WAN) interface. If your router has DHCP enable, simply put X1 to DHCP mode. If your router is not running DHCP, you had to manually enter a valid IP address for the WAN interface.

Please note that you can *not* have the same IP subnet on both the WAN and LAN interface (unless you are willing to use L2 Bridge / wire mode), so you had to carefully select your WAN/LAN subnets.

Comment: I think it's an adjacent network device that's screwing it up but I'm confident this would otherwise be the proper answer and I don't want to leave this so I'm marking it correct.